# iOS USB-C serial support

Tags: ios, serial-port, usb

We are developing a mobile app that communicates with several USB Serial devices. We are evaluating iPad Pro since it has an USB-C port and there are plenty of adapters in the market for plugging USB devices.

Does Apple provide USB Serial support for custom devices?

Can we just develop the app connecting to any serial port and communicate with the device? Are there any swift or objective c libraries to achieve this?

We are not interested in developing a custom hardware joining some Apple program or any similar solution.

Comment: Any device that communicates via the lightning or USB C port on and iOS device must be MFi certified. If you don't want to join the MFi program and customise your hardware you should look at BLE or WiFi connectivity.

Comment: thanks Paul for your comment.